# App not found in App Store by some users, but found by others

Tags: iphone, ios, mac-appstore

I have developed an app which is now publicly available in the App Store. I know other people in my organisation can find the app in the App Store with a search, yet I am unable to find the app myself, neither on my iPhone nor my iMac, using the exact same search terms.

What would be stopping me from finding the app?

Comment: whats the name of the app so I can try.

Comment: Sorry, the app's in limited pilot at the moment (but publicly available), so I don't want to tell the world just yet.

Comment: It will help if you can edit the question to add some crucial details like the supported device types for the app (iPhone only, iPad only, Universal), minimum supported iOS version for running the app, version of iOS installed on your as well as other peoples devices, version of macOS and iTunes running on your iMac etc. Having this information will better provide the information necessary to rectify your issue.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there are several possible reasons:

- Not available in the user's country
- The AppStore take some time to deliver an app update to everyone (should be available within 24 hours)
- Not available for the user's device (32bits, iPad or iPhone..)
- Phased Releases option used in AppStore Connect

This list is certainly not exhaustive*

**- How to browse iPhone App on iPad:**

http://osxdaily.com/2017/10/18/download-iphone-apps-onto-ipad/
[image]

**- 32 bits apps aren't showing up in the AppStore anymore:**

https://www.gizmodo.com.au/2017/06/32-bit-apps-arent-showing-up-in-the-app-store-but-dont-panic-yet/

Comment: The app will show up even if the iOS version is not compatible. Example: Try searching "measure" without quotes on iOS 11. The measure app will show up, but it is for iOS 12.

Comment: The only thing in the list above that might be true in this case is "The AppStore take some time to deliver an app update to everyone (should be available within 24 hours)". I shall wait...